# HttpPost returns 404 if Content-Type is set to application/json - .netcore6 api

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to write an API to handle webhook posts from Clover and their header specifies content-Type: application/json

for some reason my HttpPost method is rejecting the post with a 404 error (I assume it's my method) I can post to my endpoint no problem with Postman as long as my content-type is not application/json - as soon as I switch to that I get 404 as well

I'm missing something basic here :/ any ideas?

If I post (using Reqbin) my end point accepts and returns 200 OK

```
POST /auctionapi/Auction HTTP/1.1
Host: www.someweb.com
Content-Length: 60

{"verificationCode": "b860be7e-6ac4-4b56-8ac6-f44cf238a296"}
```

and if I change the content-type I get 404...

```
POST /auctionapi/Auction HTTP/1.1
Host: www.someweb.com
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 60

{"verificationCode": "b860be7e-6ac4-4b56-8ac6-f44cf238a296"}
```

My code...

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuctionController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly PCSOAuctionsContext _context;
    public AuctionController(PCSOAuctionsContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }      

    [HttpPost("receive")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> receive()
    {
        return StatusCode(200, "Thanks for using the API");
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown what you are actually posting, so it is very difficult for anyone to provide a suggestion.

Comment: Clover is trying to post JSON in the body {"verificationCode":"40ca3bde-e24d-429d-b407-dbd889cab241"}

Comment: You might want to redact the name of the Host header, to prevent any possible attacks on you live website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing something like this and see if that resolve the 404. The HttpPost is being sent content type of json, but your method is not setup to receive it, therefore it will 404 because a proper route is not being found.

```
[Route("pcsoauctionapi/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuctionController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly PCSOAuctionsContext _context;
    public AuctionController(PCSOAuctionsContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "PCSO Auction API", "Online" };
    }      

    [HttpPost("receive")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> receive([FromBody] object jsonData)
    {
        return StatusCode(200, "Thanks for using the API");
    }
}
```

I just tested my above method and it works just fine. So something is wrong with your Clover request. Here is result from swagger.

[image]

It shouldn't make a difference but don't set the content length and try sending then. Also can you post the CURL request clover is making. That will definitely reveal where issue is. here is my curl request.

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://localhost:7777/api/V1/receive' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"verificationCode": "b860be7e-6ac4-4b56-8ac6-f44cf238a296"}'
```

Comment: I've tried several variations of this but nothing seems to make it work :/ thanks

Comment: Can you perhaps post what you are sending? Might make it easier to diagnose with you. The API endpoint could be fine, but your send method may be the issue. I'd post that also please. Also double check ports, url, etc. all the standard stuff too

Comment: Thanks - I edited my post to show examples of what works and what doesn't

Comment: So you are sending to /pcsoauctionapi/Auction, but your method is called receive. I believe the URL might be a problem. Can you verify?

Comment: it's the only HttpPost I have in the controller and the route is set to [controller] - but it works fine if I don't set that content-type, so I *think* the URL is right? - sorry it's my first API

Comment: You can't send a post to the wrong URL, not sure why but try change the URL to /pcsoauctionapi/receive and use the method I have above and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas - but it's the same behavior - I can now post (without content-type) to https://www.pcsoweb.com/pcsoauctionapi/auction/receive - but if I set the content-type it fails - so strange!

Comment: Did you have the `[FromBody] object jsonData` in there too? Also you could try `[FromBody] string jsonData` too

Comment: Yeah I just tried both FromBody ideas and nothing works, so not even what was working before (the without content-type) now if I don't set the content-type I get "Unsupported media type" 

I do appreciate all the ideas though!

Comment: Have you referred the documentation..https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/#define-supported-request-content-types-with-the-consumes-attribute ?

Comment: Are you getting the actually API request? Like the CURL code or anything?

Comment: @GeeksGoneBad see my updated answer. its possible the content-length is over 60

Comment: I tried decorating with "Consumes" and that didn't work... I don't think I can see the curl that Clover is sending - I set up a quick beeceptor so I could see what clover is sending but all I get is the headers and body (which I posted above)

Comment: From reqbin - this curl still fails: #!/bin/bash

curl -X POST https://www.pcsoweb.com/pcsoauctionapi/auction -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"verificationCode\":\"40ca3bde-e24d-429d-b407-dbd889cab241\"}"

Comment: Your URL is wrong again? Have method like I have above and add receive to url now without content type.It might also help to see the top of your API controller method too

Comment: Yeah that's not making any difference that I can see - I even tried making the JSON body smaller just in case - but this still fails #!/bin/bash

curl -X POST https://www.pcsoweb.com/pcsoauctionapi/auction/receive -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"C\":\"d241\"}"

Comment: I'm beginning to think that somehow we're blocking application/json at the firewall or something

Comment: That could be possible, what does top of your controller look like?

Comment: [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AuctionController : ControllerBase
    {

Comment: can't post code in the comment - but it's straight out from a how to create an API tutorial LOL nothing special there

Comment: I think I see problem. Can you update your OP with the top part of your controller code. Please include all the Route stuff and the like first few lines of the controller. I will format to get this working I think.

Comment: OK I put it all up there - thanks for the help!

Comment: Ok check my latest post. Update your controller with that and make sure you deploy this to your live url of `pcsoweb.com/pcsoauctionapi/auction/receive`. I also added a Get method to further debug this so we can see if the URL is infact good and if things are being blocked cause they are app-json

Comment: it doesn't seem to like the addition of "pcsoauctionapi" to the main route - with that there nothing works, not even the get :/

Comment: Then you must have something messing with the routes. I just tested that code and it works perfectly. Do you have routes on a program.cs or startup.cs possibly? Can you copy your program.cs and if you have a startup.cs that too. omit any sensitive information obviously. I am pretty sure its a routing problem at this point and time.

Comment: since its .net core 6 you should just have the program.cs now. The fact that removing that from your controller and it made some things work tells me you have routes setup somewhere else I bet.

Comment: But everything works fine if I don't set the Content-Type in the header - wouldn't a route problem never work? I'm investigating WAF right now - thanks

Comment: It could be WAF preventing it, but I can't tell you that from code :) best of luck. Might still be helpful to post the program.cs/startup.cs just to be sure if you want.

Comment: Definitely found a block on the WAF, cleared that up and we're almost all good - for some reason the Clover request is dying between our Firewall and WAF but I have the network gurus on it! Thanks for all the help on this one!